# How can I make a button to repeat the effect?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops

I have this code and when I click the button the first time everything works ok

If I click a second time, the effect is not repeated

What is wrong with this code?

```
 function generateRandom(Event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                while (true)
             {
                 rectangle.x = xposition;
                 rectangle.y = yposition;
                 a++
             }
            }
```

Comment: not enough information here to know

Comment: is a function to move the object in a random position 
Press once and click function works ... if pressed a second time only works

Comment: what information do you need?

Comment: i don't know what your exact problem is, but that infinite loop probably isn't helping

Comment: `while(true)` will lock up your entire application. it's an infite loop. That's one of your problems, we must assume. Also, what is `xposition` and `yposition`? what is `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, generate_random_position)
function generate_random_position(e:MouseEvent){
    var x = Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth - rectangle.width)
    var y = Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - rectangle.height)
    rectangle.x = x
    rectangle.y = y
}
```